# Arraylist elements not received fully

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am using this code to transfer data in the arraylist from one activity to another and I'm got only one item that is saved on the top of the list

The code is given here:

```
ArrayList<String> ap=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ad=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> as=new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String place=add.getText().toString();
            String sta=states.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String dis=districts.getSelectedItem().toString();
                ap.add(place);
                as.add(sta);
                ad.add(dis);

            next=new Intent(AddPlace.this,MainActivity.class);
            next.putExtra("places", ap);

            next.putExtra("districts", ad);
            next.putExtra("states", as);
            startActivity(next);
```

and MainACtivity code added here:

```
ArrayList <String>vp= (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("places");
            Iterator i=vp.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (CharSequence) i.next().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

please help me

Comment: Are you sure there is more than one item in the list?

Comment: use this to pass arraylist intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key"); to retrieve

Comment: You're only asking for the `places` list, and you've only added a single item to that list. Do you understand that you've got three lists with one item in each, rather than one list with three items?

Comment: @chancea: yes.I'm inserting more than 1 item and retrieve only last inserted item on the other activity.

Answer (score 1):

To pass ArrayList throw activity, you can do like this :

**In your first activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Your_List", yourList);
startActivity(intent);
```

**In your second activity**

In your receiving intent you need to do :

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
yourList = i.getStringArrayListExtra("Your_List");
```